# If $A - LI \preceq 0$ does the largest eigenvalue of $A$ upper bounded by $L$?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ be the Hessian of some function $f,$ and
$$A - LI \preceq 0.$$
(i.e. $A - LI$ negative semi-definite.) Does this mean that the largest eigenvalue of $A$ is upper-bounded by $L$? Why?

Comment: negative semidefinite@J.D.

Answer (score 1):

Take an eigenvector $v$ as a column vector with eigenvalue $\lambda$ and transpose (row vector) $v'.$ I am assuming that $L$ is a real number. We get
$$ 0 \geq v' (A - LI) v = v' (\lambda v - Lv) = (\lambda  - L) (v' v).  $$ 
Now, $v'v$ is positive as it is the ordinary dot product of $v$ with itself, so
$$  0 \geq \lambda - L, $$
$$ L \geq \lambda .$$